# How do modern CPUs treat memory operations?

Tags: memory, cpu, bus, data

How does a modern CPU treat memory reads and writes on the hardware level?

With old 8-bit architectures all memory locations are read and written to one byte at a time, but how do modern CPUs that have much wider data buses treat 8-bit memory?

What would a modern CPU like an x86 or ARM based CPU do if it needs to read and write a value in memory which width is less than it's data bus width? AFAIK modern architectures read and write memory in chunks, so would it read and write several memory locations at a time then?

Comment: If you're asking if a 32-bit processor can read and write four different 8-bit pieces of memory in four non-sequential locations at the same time, I don't think so. Not unless they specifically accommodated for that which I'm pretty sure they don't. It should take about the same amount of time to interact with a a word as it does a byte. There is an opportunity cost.

Comment: The leading bits or bytes in a word for memory  would be 0 if unused.

Comment: IMO the data will occupy the whole word, it can be otherwise. If your memory cell has a  32-bit width, then address N will point to this cell, the address N+1 will point to a next cell of 32-bits. However you could still do mask to write each byte of this word, separately.

Comment: JustClaire, that's a design decision that varies depending on the the processor you select. In the x86 case, the transaction bus (front-side) has 7 phases to it and transfers 4 full words per transaction using 4 of the 7 phases. The others are the "transaction, error, and cache hit" phases. This is not the case for any other processor I know about. RISC processors may or may not support lane changes on a read, but usually not though. Your problem is that you imagine there is a single "modern way" of doing things. That's not truth, though. And then there's cache. Common now. Less so, before.

Comment: Different processors do things differently.  The same processor may do things differently for different types of memory or locations within.  This is unanswearable without specifics, and in a specific case you would first need to show *research effort*.

Comment: Modern memory controllers usually work in units of cache lines (32 bytes on x86), so from the memory controllers perspective an 8 bit and a 32 bit write are both a tiny fraction of the access unit.

Comment: Err should be 64 bytes per cache line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most modern CPUs (except possibly for some small embedded ones) use multiple levels of data cache between the CPU and memory subsystem.  Possibly write buffers as well.  So single bytes might be written to the a write buffer or inserted into a first level cache line. But then entire multi-byte cache lines are read from and flushed to DRAM memory, level by level, before and after, at times dependent on various cache hit, miss, pre-fetch, and dirty flush algorithms.  For IO, non-trivial PCI and on-chip controllers have different strategies for dealing with on-chip resources and devices connected to external pins that have physical buses with less than cache line or processor register size widths, using shifters and field extractors, etc.

The size of the actual physical buses (wiring) can vary widely within a single CPU or system, from many multiples of the register size, down to single bit serial.  Some are data only.  Some combine data with addressing and control bits.  So there is hardware to decipher, serialize and deserialize, pack and unpack the bits, as needed.

The memory subsystem as well can have physical bus sizes that are very different from either CPU register size, internal bus sizes, or cache line sizes.  All the way down to various serialized connections.