# What are odd-even memory addresses in 8086 and how do they work?

Tags: memory, cpu, bus, data

I have recently started to look more into microprocessors at the hardware level, and i am a bit confused on what are the odd-even memory locations that 8086 uses.

As far as i understand, it has something to do with 8086 being a 16-bit CPU while retaining the ability to access individual bytes at a time of its 8-bit predecessor 8080, but how does it work in detail?

Also, how do other early CPUs like the 68000 approach the problem of addressing individual bytes? They don't have on chip cache to read entire chunks of memory at a time nor do they have a complex MMU after all.

Comment: This is just a subset of your existing question? [How do modern CPUs treat memory operations?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/512408/how-do-modern-cpus-treat-memory-operations)  **Retaining the problems of excessive breadth and lack of self research**

Comment: @Chris Stratton It is a followup question, however my previous question has already been answered and i didn't want to add this to the old question as it would make it less specific